# How to consolidate effective_dt and expiration_dt time slices for consecutive records where certain columns remain constant?

Tags: sql, oracle

does anyone have suggestions for this problem? i am trying to use oracle SQL to consolidate spans of `effective_dt` to `expiration_dt` where values in `col_a`, `col_b`, and `col_c` remain constant, but only for consecutive records where there is no change in any of the 3 columns in between.

if it helps, it is safe to assume that the effective date of the next record (by employee) is equal to the previous record plus 1 day.

i tried with `min()`, `max()` and `group by`, but the problem is the scenario below will return 12/1-12/31. then i tried with `lead()` function, but the problem is i do not know in advance how many records i will need to consolidate.

assume that i can get the data into the form below:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+
| employee | effective_dt | expiration_dt |  col_a  |  col_b  |  col_c  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+
|     0001 | 12/1/2012    | 12/4/2012     | value_a | value_a | value_a |
|     0001 | 12/5/2012    | 12/6/2012     | value_a | value_a | value_a |
|     0001 | 12/7/2012    | 12/10/2012    | value_a | value_a | value_a |
|     0001 | 12/11/2012   | 12/17/2012    | value_a | value_b | value_a |
|     0001 | 12/18/2012   | 12/31/2012    | value_a | value_a | value_a |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

expected result:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+
| employee | effective_dt | expiration_dt |  col_a  |  col_b  |  col_c  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+
|     0001 | 12/1/2012    | 12/10/2012    | value_a | value_a | value_a |
|     0001 | 12/11/2012   | 12/17/2012    | value_a | value_b | value_a |
|     0001 | 12/18/2012   | 12/31/2012    | value_a | value_a | value_a |
+----------+--------------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

attempt 1:

```
SELECT employee,
  MIN(effective_dt),
  MAX(expiration_dt),
  col_a,
  col_b,
  col_c
FROM
  (SELECT employee, effective_dt, ... FROM table_x, table_y, ... where...
  ) table_a
GROUP BY employee,
  col_a,
  col_b,
  col_c;
```

attempt 2:

```
SELECT employee,
  effective_dt,
  lead(expiration_dt, 1) over (partition BY employee, col_a, col_b, col_c order by effective_dt) expiration_dt,
  col_a,
  col_b,
  col_c
FROM
  (SELECT employee, effective_dt, ... FROM table_x, table_y, ... where...
  ) table_a;
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case we can, as you state, safely assume that next record equals previous record + 1 day, then we can chain these records up:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b0eb/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (employee int, effective_dt timestamp, expiration_dt timestamp, col_a varchar2(7), col_b varchar2(7), col_c varchar2(7))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t (employee, effective_dt, expiration_dt, col_a, col_b, col_c)
         VALUES (0001, '01-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', '04-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', 'value_a', 'value_a', 'value_a')
    INTO t (employee, effective_dt, expiration_dt, col_a, col_b, col_c)
         VALUES (0001, '05-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', '06-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', 'value_a', 'value_a', 'value_a')
    INTO t (employee, effective_dt, expiration_dt, col_a, col_b, col_c)
         VALUES (0001, '07-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', '10-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', 'value_a', 'value_a', 'value_a')
    INTO t (employee, effective_dt, expiration_dt, col_a, col_b, col_c)
         VALUES (0001, '11-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', '17-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', 'value_a', 'value_b', 'value_a')
    INTO t (employee, effective_dt, expiration_dt, col_a, col_b, col_c)
         VALUES (0001, '18-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', '19-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', 'value_a', 'value_b', 'value_a')
    INTO t (employee, effective_dt, expiration_dt, col_a, col_b, col_c)
         VALUES (0001, '20-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', '31-Dec-2012 12:00:00 AM', 'value_a', 'value_a', 'value_a')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select employee, min(effective_dt), max(expiration_dt), col_a, col_b, col_c 
  from ( select t.*, 
                case when
                     col_a = lag(col_a) over (partition by employee order by expiration_dt asc)    
                 and col_b = lag(col_b) over (partition by employee order by expiration_dt asc) 
                 and col_c = lag(col_c) over (partition by employee order by expiration_dt asc) 
                then 0 else 1 end start_of_chain 
           from t
  )
 connect by effective_dt = prior expiration_dt + 1  and start_of_chain = 0  
   start with start_of_chain = 1
   group by connect_by_root(effective_dt), employee, col_a, col_b, col_c
order by 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b0eb/7/0)**:

```
| EMPLOYEE |               MIN(EFFECTIVE_DT) |              MAX(EXPIRATION_DT) |   COL_A |   COL_B |   COL_C |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 | December, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000 | December, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000 | value_a | value_a | value_a |
|        1 | December, 11 2012 00:00:00+0000 | December, 19 2012 00:00:00+0000 | value_a | value_b | value_a |
|        1 | December, 20 2012 00:00:00+0000 | December, 31 2012 00:00:00+0000 | value_a | value_a | value_a |
```

Comment: this is every helpful, i didn't even know about hierarchical queries before... thank you!